# связать 2 текстовых поля через чистый js

Tags: javascript

у меня такой вопрос, есть 2 поля которые нужно связать, оставляю код:

```
<span>Номер отделения</span>
<input  type="text" required  size="90px" id="departament" oninput="input()">
<span>Адрес отделения</span>
<input  type="text" required  size="90px" id="address" disabled>
```

задание такое, человек пишет в поле "номер отделения", например номер  отделения 1, ему сразу в поле "адрес отделения" вбивается адрес этого отделения. то есть допустим есть 5 отделений, и у каждого свой адрес, поле "адрес отделения" не доступен для редактирования, туда автоматически вбивается адрес, я пытался сделать с помощью oninput, но что то не зашло, сказано что номер отделения и адрес берется из массива, и подставляется, подскажите варианты решения, возможно через  цикл как то подставлять, спасибо

```
  var dep_address=new Array();
        dep_address[0]=1;
        dep_address[1]="address 1 departament";
        dep_address[2]=2;
        dep_address[3]="address 2 departament";
        dep_address[4]=3;
        dep_address[5]="address 3 departament";
        dep_address[6]=4;
        dep_address[7]="address 4 departament";
        dep_address[8]=5;
        dep_address[9]="address 5 departament";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function inputDep(el) {
  var dep_address = [
    { number: 1, address: "address 1 departament" },
    { number: 2, address: "address 2 departament" },
    { number: 3, address: "address 3 departament" },
    { number: 4, address: "address 4 departament" },
    { number: 5, address: "address 5 departament" },
    { number: 6, address: "address 6 departament" },
  ];
  var item = dep_address.find(function(i) { return i.number == el.value; });
  if (item)
    document.getElementById("address").value = item.address;
}
```

```html
<span>Номер отделения</span>
<input  type="text" required  size="90px" id="departament" oninput="inputDep(this)">
<span>Адрес отделения</span>
<input  type="text" required  size="90px" id="address" disabled>
```

---

- `dep_adress` - это массив объектов,

> почему тогда в этом массиве у переменной number значение не через "="
>   а через ":"

- *object literal* - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
- `find` - это метод типа `Array`, который принимает в качестве параметра функцию - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp

Comment: все заработало, огромное спасибо, но я не знаю еще многих вещей в JS, не могли бы вы прочитать код который написали, был бы очень благодарен

Comment: @РоманРомашко Правильнее, я думаю, будет, если Вы скажете, что Вам непонятно в коде ответа.

Comment: переменная dep_adress это объект массивов, если я правильно понимаю) но почему тогда в этом массиве у переменной number значение не через "=" а через ":" и adress так же само. и второй вопрос что означает find вот здесь dep_address.find?

Comment: понял, спасибо, буду дальше разбираться